# Python timers engine

Tags: python

I need to write a python daemon that runs python scripts and send the output of them over TCP to server. Each script should be run every N seconds (for example, the first - every 10 seconds, the second - every 3 seconds and the third - every 200 seconds, etc.).
When running, the daemon looks for config file that contains paths to scripts and their time delay(shoul I call above seconds like that?). And then this daemon calls scripts in due time.

The question I'm asking about is how can I make this simple timer engine? Are there any ready solutions?

P.S. I have one idea. This idea is something like that:

1. Initialize start time(time of launching daemon) - start_time
2. Make an array of script's time delay - time_delays[]
3. Every second do that thing:

   ```
   now_time = int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())

   for x in time_delays:

       diff = start_time - now_time             

       if diff % x == 0:

           # Good! Let's run script file
   ```

Comment: I would suggest you try the idea you came up with and come back if it doesn't work as intended or you run into any programming related problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a scheduler, see the api here https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/# Here is a quick example:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
import logging
logging.basicConfig()

def t1():
    #run file1 with a PUB\SUB routine

def t2():
    #run file2 with a PUB\SUB routine

def t3():
    #run file3 with a PUB\SUB routine

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    sched.add_interval_job(t1, minutes=1, start_date='2013-08-06 00:09:12')
    scheduler.add_job(t2, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=1, minute=2)
    scheduler.add_job(t3, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=1, second=10)
    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))
    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Your simple question masks what will in the end be something more complicated.
You are going to need a configuration function, a timer function, threads and pubsub (or some other mechanism) to communicate that the script has completed and finally sockets or ftp to communicate with the servers, a list of which will also have to kept, or individually noted in the configuration file against each script.
I'm assuming, multiple servers, multiple scripts that could be running at the same time and scripts that can take a long or short time to finish.
How you garner the results of the scripts work will also impact your choice of the method used to communicate to each server, you may have to use different methods depending on the nature of the scripts result.